# wp_logout action not working

Tags: actions, cookies, logout

I'm trying to remove some cookies set to control persistent login when the user specifically wants to log out of a website.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
function remove_user_cookie() {

    unset($_COOKIE['woai']);
    unset($_COOKIE['woak']);

}
add_action('wp_logout', 'remove_user_cookie');
```

I've also tried:

```
function remove_user_cookie() {

    if( $_GET['action'] == 'logout' ) :

        unset($_COOKIE['woai']);
        unset($_COOKIE['woak']);

    endif;

}
add_action('wp_logout', 'remove_user_cookie');
```

However, the users cookies remain in place, so they keep getting logged back in automatically.

I'm not sure if the wp_logout action just isn't working, or if it's clashing with my code that logs the user in automatically.

Right now, I have this in the header.php:

```
<?php if( !is_user_logged_in() ) :

    // check if user has cookies
    if ( isset($_COOKIE['woai']) && isset($_COOKIE['woak']) ) :

        $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'login_key',
            'meta_value' => $_COOKIE['woak'],
            'meta_compare' => '=',
            'fields' => 'ID',
            'include' => $_COOKIE['woai']
        );
        $user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

        if( $user_query->results[0] != '' || $user_query->results[0] != NULL ) :

            // get user id and login name
            $user_id = $user_query->results[0];
            $user_login = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

            // log the user in
            wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login->user_login );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );

            do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login->user_login );

        endif;

    endif; // end if cookies

endif; ?>
```

And when the user is logged in, they get a new key set with this:

```
function set_user_cookie($user_login) {

    // if they have cookies, delete them
    if ( isset($_COOKIE['woai']) && isset($_COOKIE['woak']) ) :
        unset($_COOKIE['woai']);
        unset($_COOKIE['woak']);
    endif;

    $user_id = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login );

    // generate new key for user
    $salt = wp_generate_password(20); // 20 character "random" string
    $key = sha1($salt . $email . uniqid(time(), true));

    // set new cookies
    setcookie("woai", $user_id->ID, time()+31536000);  /* expire in 1 year */
    setcookie("woak", $key, time()+31536000);  /* expire in 1 year */

    // update the db
    update_field('field_53c3de9cd031e', $key, 'user_'.$user_id->ID.'');

}
add_action('wp_login', 'set_user_cookie', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Rather than using `unset($_COOKIE['woai'])`, did you tried `setcookie("woak", '', time() - 3600 );` ?

Answer (score 1):

pls try below code

```
function remove_user_cookie() {

setcookie("woak");
setcookie("woai");

}
add_action('wp_logout', 'remove_user_cookie');
```

apart why you use cookie to storing some value ? suggest you to use session

Comment: This didn't work I'm afraid. I'm using cookies because this is for a persistent login, so the users need to keep a cookie so I know if they need to be auto-logged in or not :)

Answer (score 0):

(I created a persistent login for my client, one login for two wordpress based site, on prestashop and 3 custom php application).
I had the same challenge but this is the way i solved it.

First step

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'doMyLogoutCall');
add_action('init', 'runInitLogoutProcess');
```

second step

```
function doMyLogoutCall()
{?>
 <img style="display:none" src="<?php echo home_url();
    ?>?loadwordpressbyimage=1">
<?php
}

function runInitLogoutProcess()
{
  // check if wordpress action is set to logout and clear cookie
  if (isset($_GET)) {
        if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            if ($_GET['action'] == 'logout') {
                setcookie('woai', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
               setcookie('woak', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
            }
        }

  // check if your wp_logout hook is called and do the same.
      if (isset($_GET['loadwordpressbyimage'])) {
            if ($_GET['loadwordpressbyimage'] == 1) {
                setcookie('woak', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
               setcookie('woai', '', time() - 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
            }
        }


}
```

//That's it.